# Exchange security guidance (not cross posting, just making you aware)

Tags: discussion

I have a question on Sec.SE that is probably of interest to everyone here, however I don't want to cross post the same question.  I've never tried posting a topic of interest on Meta in this way, so I don't know what to expect.

For those who are interested in the secure deployment of Exchange please see this link:

https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40654/396

**For Serverfault Meta**

If you think this "cross site question promotion" is not right for serverfault meta, you wish to downvote me for any reason, feel explain your perspectives and feel free to do so in the area(s) below.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of thoughts...

1. Cross site "promotion" of questions isn't allowed. I believe you correctly assess that the sites have different visitors/frequenters, and that posting on one site essentially precludes the opposing audience from ever seeing your post. It's still not allowed. This is my biggest gripe with IT Security, DBA, Networking, Unix & Linux, and minor parts of several other sites. They sites splinter the community much more than they organize it.
2. Since your problem is not theoretical it's completely on-topic for SF as well. If you want it can be migrated; though I doubt that's your intention as you'd be in the exact same problem reversed.
3. **Meta doesn't work like SF: Voting has no effect on your reputation.** It does not indicate how good or bad your post is; it indicates how much people agree or disagree with whatever you're saying. Posts tend to get a lot more voting on Meta because of this.
4. Posts on Meta.SF should be regarding Server Fault: a question/post there, the site itself, or the community as a whole. Problems with individuals should be brought to moderators attention, unless it's a moderator, then you contact the community teams (see link at bottom of every page). This question is mostly off-topic...

Comment: I think there should be a way to do cross site promotion.  If meta isn't the place, and chatroom is too noisy; this is a problem area that can be solved with enough thought.

Comment: I agree that I would get + or - votes on cross site promotion here on meta, but never saw an official statement on that.  By official, I mean meta.StackOverflow, since the rules of meta.SO or blog.stackexchange seem to take precedent  over meta.

Comment: The cross-site thing has been brought up before, debated, tons of proposals (including mine, a hierarchical solution), and declined. And the sites have proliferated... It's not a new problem by any means, and you're not the first to be annoyed by it. If you can get SE to change I'd be impressed and in your debt.

Comment: See [faq#vote-differences] for details on what is supposed to be posted here. Network wide changes are announced on the blog and mSO, but their site rules don't apply (past being the basis for mSF's rules...)

Comment: Understood.  I'll leave this open for a while longer and won't abuse this experiment (e.g. trying to use this meta question as a guise to cross post my Sec.SE question).  I'm mostly looking for any dissenting opinions and whatever they come up with.

Comment: FWIW, there already *is* cross-site promotion by the means of "hot questions". Obviously, you have very little influence over what is appearing there as the question's owner. As the number of sites has increased and keeps increasing, the need for cross-site promotion will continue to rise, so maybe it is going to be implemented one day.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should pick the best site for your question (which I think you did -- it's definitely a security question at its heart), and you definitely shouldn't cross-post (which you didn't do - so far you're being awesome!)

This isn't really a "Meta" topic though (it's not about Server Fault as a site).
The better way to get eyes on an off-site question is probably to just pop in to [SF chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127/the-comms-room) and let us know about the question and that you'd like some sysadmins to look at it too in case we have an idea on mitigating the big gaping security hole Microsoft has given you

(We usually don't bite - hard.)

Comment: Not very many people use chat however... This one only seems mildly relevant as there are several people who Exchange administration in chat. If the question was about Gentoo, he'd probably get more mocking than help from chat.

Comment: Anyone using Gentoo deserves mocking. :)